# Client Side rendering and hiding functionality due to Permissions

Tags: javascript, authorization

I have always been a server side rendering developer (JSP/Struts) and we are moving to client side rendering (VueJS).  I see 100% client side rendering as a security 'issue' (I think).  In that, the HTML returned to the browser will contain ALL functionality, even though a particular user may not be authorized to do something (and, therefore, will not be rendered).  For example, imagine a page that shows a Widget.  There is a 'Delete Widget' button (that, on click, calls /Widget/delete).  This user does not have authorization to do a delete.  No problem not showing the Delete button, and, of course, the server side code will check authorization and deny any user who is not authorized. But I feel returning that snippet of HTML to the browser (even though it isn't rendered) is not good.  Am I overthinking this?

Comment: you bind permissions to a user. Any user specific action you can perform in your client side should communicate with an API that requires user information (an access token for instance) to evaluate each action. With this it's not so insecure anymore. With the user info the System that provides the API can decide to permit or deny the action. The user might be able to enable the button in the inspector but when clicking it will get an error

Comment: Totally understand.  So you feel it's OK to expose (in the source, not the rendered page) functionality that the user cannot execute?  Seems to me a user shouldn't even know Widget/delete even exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's no secret that your application supports delete.

As long as the /Widget/delete entry point is properly secured (with authentication, authorization, and CSRF protection), there should be no security problems created by downloading code that calls it.